# First time working with classes in C++ : request for member of non class type

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I've edited this after what you guys have told me. It gets all the way to this line and errors

cout << "The starting speed is " << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl

[Error] request for member 'getSpeed' in 'honda', which is of non-class type 'Car(int, std::string, int) {aka Car(int, std::basic_string, int)}'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car  {
private:
    int yearModel;
    string make;
    int speed;

public:
    Car(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed = 0) {
        yearModel = carYearModel;
        make = carMake;
        speed = carSpeed; 
    }

    void accelerate() {
        speed += 5;
    }

    void brake() {
        speed -= 5;
    }

    int getSpeed() {
        return speed; 
    }

    int getyearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }

    string getMake() {
        return make; 
    }
 };

int main() {

int count, YearModel, speed, make;
string carMake;

cout <<  "What is the speed?";
cin  >>  speed;

cout << "What is the year of the model?";
cin  >> YearModel;

cout << "What is the make?";
cin  >> make;

Car honda(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed);

cout << "The starting speed is " << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl;
cout << "The year and model is  " << honda.getyearModel() << endl << endl;
cout << "The make of the car is "  << honda.getMake() << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do your getter methods ask for inputs? That is kind of strange, O_O

Comment: I'm a beginner in my second semester of college. Thanks for the insight!!

Comment: Could anyone help me with this error I'm getting? Thanks!

Comment: What error? Do none of the answers below help?

Comment: Yes, they do indeed, I've made revisions but still get the same error. It's when I try to call the function towards the end that I get this error. on this line cout << "The starting speed is " << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl;                                                                                 [Error] request for member 'getSpeed' in 'honda', which is of non-class type 'Car(int, std::string, int) {aka Car(int, std::basic_string<char>, int)}'

Comment: In your updated code above, you did not remove the data types from the statement and also, you are using wrong names: `Car honda(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed);`. It should be `Car honda(YearModel,  make, speed);`. **Also, your declaration of the variables are wrong**: `int count, YearModel, speed, make;
string carMake;`; it should be `int count, speed, YearModel; string make;` Please see my code below; maybe you are using the older versions of the code I posted. I edited it quite a lot of times due to mistakes from copy and paste.

Comment: You need to fix the declaration of variable types :S, @Ben

Comment: After having tried that, let me know if you still have error(s).

Comment: is it fixed now? @Ben

Comment: Sorry, had to doze off for a few. Thank you so much! It runs now :D I see what I did wrong as well. I appreciate it Tacocat!

Comment: It is starred! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter methods should not be asking for user inputs.

Also, it should be Car honda(carYearModel, carMake, carSpeed); and you need to assign values to the variables carYearModel, carMake` and carSpeed before you can use them as method arguments. You can get these values from the user. You do not include the argument data types when calling the method. You only do that when defining the method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car  {
    private:
        int yearModel;
        string make;
        int speed;

    public:
        Car(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed = 0) {
            yearModel = carYearModel;
            make = carMake;
            speed = carSpeed; 
        }

        void accelerate() {
            speed += 5;
        }

        void brake() {
            speed -= 5;
        }

        int getSpeed() {
            return this.speed; 
        }

        int getyearModel() {
            return this.yearModel;
        }

        string getMake() {
            return this.make; 
        }
};

int main() {

    int count, carYearModel, carSpeed;
    string carMake;

    cout <<  "What is the speed?";
    cin  >> carSpeed;

    cout << "What is the year of the model?";
    cin  >> carYearModel;

    cout << "What is the make?";
    cin  >> carMake;

    Car honda(carYearModel, carMake, carSpeed);

    cout << "The starting speed is " << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl;
    cout << "The year and model is  " << honda.getyearModel() << endl << endl;
    cout << "The make of the car is "  << honda.getMake() << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `Car honda = new Car` does not compile because you have a type mismatch. Also passing in `int carYearModel` does not work.

Comment: @Tas My bad. Did not see that the `make` was defined as a `string` in the class. Crap. I thought this was Java. SORRY!

Answer (score 2):

```
Car honda(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed);
```

declares a function named `honda` that takes three arguments are returns a `Car`. What you need is:

```
int carYearModel = 2015;    // Some value
string carMake =  "Honda";  // Makes sense to define honda
int carSpeed = 155;         // Some value

// Create an object of type Car
Car honda(carYearModel, carMake, carSpeed);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's probably not apparent by my mess of a program, but I'm trying to use accessor functions to get the values stored in the objects yearModel, make and speed variables. So I'd like to set these values in the member functions, getSpeed(), getMake(), getyearModel(). Also should these be "set" rather than "get" functions? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Ben You should probably define both `getters` and `setters` for your class then! Separately.

Comment: If you want to set the values of the members of class, it makes sense to define functions such as `setSpeed`, `setMake`, and `setYearModel`. The `getXXX` functions should return the values of the members of the class.